Transform list items without an outer map
I want to learn more about Kotlin and specifically streams. I'm just doing some homework exercises basically.
One exercise reads: Start with a list of strings containing both uppercase and lowercase letters. Filter out the lowercase letters, convert the remaining uppercase letters to lowercase, and then sort them alphabetically.
That's not too hard:
val strings: List<String> = listOf(...)

return strings
        .flatMap { it.toList() }
        .filter(Char::isUpperCase)
        .map(Char::lowercaseChar)
        .sorted()

This solution creates a List of everything in the list, but to one up myself I want to do the same, but then per string. So it would return a List<List<Char>>.
The only thing I can come up with is
return strings.map { str ->
    str.filter(Char::isUpperCase)
        .map(Char::lowercaseChar)
        .sorted()
}

So now there is basically two parts: the outer map and the inner filter/map/sort. I really want to do this in one go.
Is that possible and how so?

Well, you apply transformations to individual items, not the the list as a whole, so it makes sense to keep these transformations inside the map. Trying to somehow "do this in one go", if at all possible, will most probably make the code less readable.

No, I think you can only do something like this:
strings.map(String::doStuff)

For this to work you'll need this function:
fun String.doStuff() = this
    .filter(Char::isUpperCase)
    .map(Char::lowercaseChar)
    .sorted()

This may seem cheated at first glance, but it would actually be preferable in terms of readability(*). Although you can put everything in one monolithic function chain, it is clearer if you separate the handling of the list from the string manipulation logic. Since the latter isn't trivial it benefits from being isolated from the rest.
(*): Apart from the function name, obviously. You should pick something that better describes what this function does.

Making an extension function is probably unwarranted at this stage, but you make an excellent point. Even if you can, you shouldn't.
